# R language Warning when concatenating using rbind

Tags: r, concatenation, rbind

In R, I am concatenating 4 data files with identical variable names in each of the four files with:

```
ps <- rbind(ps1, ps2, ps3, ps4)
```

Each of the 4 files have data that was read without error using the `read.xls()` function. However, after the `rbind()` command, I get the following warning messages and some of the data are incorrect (by being set to missing) in the file produced by `rbind()` even though the data are correct in the 4 individual data files.

```
Warning messages:
1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
2: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = c(343L, 343L, NA, 343L, NA,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
3: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = c(54L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 55L,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
4: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

I have no idea what these messages mean or how to resolve my problem. Your help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Why? If your data had character values and you accepted the default settings for the read.table function then you got factor columns and the different dataframes may not have had the same set of values.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest fix is that when reading the `XLS` files you can set `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`.

What happened is that some column got converted into a `factor` but each file got its own `factor` and they cannot be combined automatically.

For further reading: [Loading Data From a File](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Data_input_and_output/Loading_data_from_a_file/), [Factors in R](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/factors.html)

Comment: This worked: Probably the easiest fix is that when reading the XLS files you can set stringsAsFactors=FALSE       THANKS!

Comment: @user2502904 You're welcome. Please "accept" my answer if you like it. You can read more about how to handle answers on StackOverflow (and other Stack Exchange sites) here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Try this before your rbinding:

```
pstmp <- lapply( list (ps1, ps2, ps3, ps4), 
                  function(df) as.data.frame( 
                        lapply(df, if (is.factor(cl)){ as.character(cl)
                                       } else {cl} ) ) )
```

Then:

```
ps <- do.call(rbind, pstmp)
```

(Crossing my fingers that I got the parens and braces correct.) Or do what OldPro suggests. It's also possible to turn off automatic factor construction with `options()`.